# Jackson Java Object mapping fails reporting non-existent 'known properties'

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON object that is being mapped to a Java Object. The JSON contains nested data which the Java Object handles. My case is large so I will use a cut down version as an example of what I am attempting.

My JSON data looks like this:

`{"name":"wmi", "data": [{"ip":"192.168.1.50", "L2CacheSize":"1024", "L2CacheSpeed":"0"}, {"ip":"192.168.1.51", "L2CacheSize":"1024", "L2CacheSpeed":"0"}] }`

where the data field holds a list of further JSON objects. This is mapped via Jackson to my Java Object that looks like this:

```
public class WmiData {
    private String name;
    private List<Computer> data;

    //Getters and Setters...

    //Constructor
    public WmiData(String name, List<Computer> computers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = computers;
    }

    static class Computer {
        private String ip;
        private Integer L2CacheSize;
        private Integer L2CacheSpeed;

        public Computer(String ip, Integer L2CacheSize, Integer L2CacheSpeed) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.L2CacheSize = L2CacheSize;
            this.L2CacheSpeed = L2CacheSpeed;
        }

        //Getters and Setters...

    }
}
```

and I am doing a simple mapping like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
WmiData data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, WmiData.class);
```

However, the parsing fails giving an error:

```
SEVERE: Failure to convert json to object:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "L2CacheSize" (class company.Data.Wmi$Computer), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: , "ip", "l2CacheSize", "l2CacheSpeed")
 at [Source: {"data":[{"L2CacheSize":"1024","ip":"192.168.1.50","L2CacheSpeed":"0"}, {"L2CacheSize":"1024","ip":"192.168.1.51","L2CacheSpeed":"0"}],"name":"wmi"}; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: company.Data.Wmi["data"]->company.Data.Computer["L2CacheSize"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:568)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:649)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:830)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:310)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:226)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:203)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:338)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:87)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2563)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1805)
        at uk.co.humboldt.Sums.Service.MessageHandler.getPoll(MessageHandler.java:93)
        at uk.co.humboldt.Sums.Service.MessageHandler.pollWmi(MessageHandler.java:147)
        at uk.co.humboldt.Sums.Service.MessageHandler.pollServices(MessageHandler.java:105)
        at uk.co.humboldt.Sums.Service.MessageHandler.lambda$new$0(MessageHandler.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error above explains that Jackson is only aware of three known properties `ip`, `l2CacheSize` and `l2CacheSpeed`, two of which do not exist in my object definition. My fields are `L2CacheSize` and `L2CacheSpeed`, note the capital 'L' in both. The data source it seems to complain it is incompatible with clearly shows that the incoming data is in the exact same format as described by my Java Objects but yet fails.

What could be the problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: L2CacheSize is a string, you mapped it with an int, change that to string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that Jackson uses Java Bean naming conventions, to figure it out the Json properties in a Java class.

So, to solve it you can change your property names to the ones Jackson says he "know" or annotate it with `@JsonProperty("L2CacheSize")` as example.

```
static class Computer {
    private String ip;

    @JsonProperty("L2CacheSize")
    private Integer L2CacheSize;

    @JsonProperty("L2CacheSpeed")
    private Integer L2CacheSpeed;

    public Computer(String ip, Integer L2CacheSize, Integer L2CacheSpeed) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.L2CacheSize = L2CacheSize;
        this.L2CacheSpeed = L2CacheSpeed;
    }

    //Getters and Setters...

}
```

Comment: I was not having this problem when performing the same actions on a class that contained much simpler variable names. Is this honestly just Jackson looking for specifically Camel-case variable names?

Comment: Yeah, as I pointed Jackson use Java beans naming conventions, that is the name must be camel case and there are other rules too, but the one your are violating is the camel case, if you name your variables like l2CacheSize it should work without the annotation

Comment: That seems horribly designed IMHO, as it essentially transforms an already defined variable name into an incorrect one. It doesn't make sense that it wouldn't have explicit property definition as mandatory in this case as silently adhering to a naming conventions just seems misleading, confusing and wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Shiri, there is a reason for using it, it's a technique for getting the information about the class such as fields and methods that doesn't require too much use of Reflection, or otherwise it would be slow. I forgot the name of the technique, but it's just to replace the use of reflection, the problem is with the getter and setter methods generated, according to the Beans convention the getter should be get + the name of the variable following camelcase, since your getter will be L2CacheSize it will assume the property is l2CacheSize, thus following the convention.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kennedy. You've cleared things up, much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

Just set the DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
WmiData data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, WmiData.class);
```